# No resource identifier found for attribute 'weight' in package 'android'?

Tags: android, xml

I keep getting this error when i compile: No resource identifier found for attribute 'weight' in package 'android'. How can i fix this? Code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<TextView

    android:text="@string/enter_name" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    />

<EditText 
    android:hint="@string/hint_one"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weight="1"
    />
<EditText 
    android:hint="@string/hint_two"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weight="1"
    />

<Button
    android:text="@string/send_message"   
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    />
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's `android:layout_weight="1"`

Comment: Thanks! Another question if you don't mind? why won't the 'EditText' appear? The button and text view show, however.

Comment: layout_weight is only appropriate inside a LinearLayout.  This is a RelativeLayout so if you specify height or width 0dp, that's the actual size you will get and the weight will be ignored